# Scanner "Input cannot be solved to a variable" error

Tags: java, input

So I'm a complete noob at Java and experimenting with a calculator.  The code below is what I have so far.  The problem is that the code works until I add the label "loops:", after adding the label the Scanner gets an error for some reason.  I want the loops label so that the user can choose (if statement at bottom of code) whether or not to continue using the calculator.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class MainClass {



    public MainClass(){

        loops:

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println("First Number: ");
        int number1 = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Second Number: ");
        int number2 = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Operator (+, -, /, *)");
        String operation = input.next();
        String cont = input.next();

        int total;

        if(operation.equals("+")){
            total = number1 + number2;
            System.out.println(total);
        }
        if(operation.equals("-")){
            total = number1 - number2;
            System.out.println(total);
        }
        if(operation.equals("*")){
            total = number1 * number2;
            System.out.println(total);
        }
        if(operation.equals("/")){
            total = number1 / number2;
            System.out.println(total);
        }

        System.out.println("Continue? Y/N: ");
        if (cont.equalsIgnoreCase("n")){
            break loops;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainClass();


    }

}
```

Comment: I guess `loops:` is a type in `MainClass` constructor

Comment: `loops:` is not legitimate - in Java we don't have labels

Comment: Use a loop (while or for loop) rather than labels and goto (which don't exist in Java). Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html. And when you get an error, read the error message. It's informative. If you don't understand it, post it. It's informative for us as well, and we can explain them to you.

Comment: @alfasin: yes we have them (although nobody uses them). We don't have goto though.

Comment: you can label loops in Java alright but I don't see any for/while loop though after your label 'loops'

Comment: Okay so its not typo. Read this is what you need. [`The for Statement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)  **OR** [`The while and do-while Statements`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)

Comment: you've defined a variable **input** with a lowercase 'i' while your error mentions **Input** with a capital 'I'?

Comment: @JBNizet you're right - my bad! I think that he can't use it just like that inside a body of a class - only inside methods, no ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a loop. Labels do exist though, you are just no using them properly. Labels can essentially name a loop so that you can break / continue specific loops.

Answer (score 0):

See the fixed class below (there was another issue - with `cont`), the following code works for me:

```
import java.util.Scanner;    

public class MainClass {

    public MainClass(){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(true){
            System.out.println("First Number: ");
            int number1 = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Second Number: ");
            int number2 = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Operator (+, -, /, *)");
            String operation = input.next();

            int total;
            if(operation.equals("+")){
                total = number1 + number2;
                System.out.println(total);
            }
            else if(operation.equals("-")){
                total = number1 - number2;
                System.out.println(total);
            }
            else if(operation.equals("*")){
                total = number1 * number2;
                System.out.println(total);
            }
            else if(operation.equals("/")){
                total = number1 / number2;
                System.out.println(total);
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Undefined input!"); 
            }
            System.out.println("Continue? Y/N: ");
            String cont = input.next();
            if (cont.equalsIgnoreCase("n")){
                 break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            new MainClass();
    }
}
```

BTW, I don't like doing these things inside a constructor, maybe that's just my personal taste, but I'd rather define it in a method (static or not static - up to you) and call that method from `main`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code firstly requires a **break** statement in each of your switch cases.Secondly labels if used cannot be applied to variable declarations.That answers why you get an error with Scanner.I suggest you use a do-while loop which is a entry controlled loop,syntax goes like this

```
   do
   {
      //code you want to execute,will get executed at least once 
   }

   while(boolean condition);
```

You can place your switch cases in the do part and whether or not the user wants to continue will go as your boolean condition in the while part.Try it!